# Improve conceptual intervalometer for rotating potted plants

Tags: design, comparator, hysteresis, hobbyist

I'm trying to avoid having my plants tilting or otherwise looking bad after only getting sunlight from one direction. To solve it, I want to make the pots rotate.

I'm trying to design a cheap, stand alone, solar powered solution. My idea is to slowly charge a super cap with a small solar panel, then once there is enough energy stored up, send an impulse to a motor to turn the pot slightly and then slowly charge up again. Does it seem like a viable solution?

[image]

Specifically, I feel like there must be some way to replace the flip/flop. Could I use a comparator with a very big hysteresis? That is, use voltage instead of time (as in pic). A hysteresis which spans the majority of the energy of the capacitor, like 4V.

Comment: You might want to breadboard it up, but using a zener to trigger an SCR sounds like it could be a simple solution to your problem here.

Comment: I don't see the principle where the pot shall follow the sun. There is always a possibility that it will turn too much or too little. Can you elaborate?

Comment: No electrical design can begin till U have energy and position specs which need numbers and a low friction turntable with a low friction motor and position feedback

Comment: Thanks @vir! An SCR sounds just like the thing I was looking for! I guess, however, that it will turn off at a very low voltage? That means my voltage booster would have to cold start every cycle. But that should be ok :)

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for precise or repeatable motion, just something to nudge the pot around a few degrees every so often so the plants don't grow sideways.  If the capacitor is only able to power the motor for a few hundred milliseconds at a time a couple of times a day that should be enough.

Comment: Exactly, thanks.

Comment: Consider simplifying the design greatly turning the pots very very slowly whenever the solar cell is receiving sun.  Power is the product of torque and speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into [BEAM solar engines](http://faq.solarbotics.net/oscillate.html). The concept is similar to what you've outlined above but less complex. You use a small solar cell to charge a capacitor. When the capacitor reaches a certain voltage, a transistor dumps the charge through a motor. In the [original case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solarroller), the motor moved a tiny robot a few inches. In your case it could rotate your plant a few degrees. The various timings depend on the size of the solar cell, size of the capacitor, and amount of light the system receives. Discussion and various circuits can be found [here](http://solarbotics.net/library/circuits/se.html).

[image]

The original circuit as developed by Mark Tilden...

Edit: The full solarbotics library is [here](http://solarbotics.net/library.html)- lots of goodies...